# What is $O$ such that measuring $O(|\phi\rangle\otimes|0\rangle)$ gives $\langle\phi|H|\phi\rangle$ for $H=\frac13 X+\frac12 I$?

Tags: quantum-state

Can someone help me with the following question:

Consider a one-qubit Hamiltonian $ H = \frac{1}{3}X + \frac{1}{2}I $. Give a two-qubit operator $ O $ such that when $ O $ is applied to $ |\phi\rangle \otimes |0\rangle $ and the second bit is measured in the standard basis, then the probability of measuring 0 is $ \langle\phi|H|\phi\rangle $.

This look a lot like the Hadamard Test, but I haven't been able to crack it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the following circuit?
[image]
Using the parameter $\theta$ lets you adjust the strength of the $X$ term. In this case, I believe you want $\sin\theta=\frac23$, if I take $R_Y(\theta)=e^{-iY\theta/2}$.

The basic idea is that after the controlled-not, the two-qubit system is in a state
$$
|0\rangle|\phi\rangle+|1\rangle X|\phi\rangle.
$$
You want an extra operation that, on the $|0\rangle$ component, is going to give you an output $\alpha|\phi\rangle+\beta X|\phi\rangle$. The $R_Y$ rotation is a nice way to achieve this, ensuring that $\alpha,\beta$ are real.